# typescript: untyped array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Just for fun, I decided to look at TypeScript.

I have one question (so far); given the following typescript code...

```
class EP {

  id: number;
  TY: string;

  constructor(id: number, ty: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.TY = ty;
  }

}
```

and the following typescript code...

```
var ep = new EP(1, "Yes");
var x = [ep.id, ep.TY];
```

JavaScript would see this as valid, however TypeScript is complaining of "Incompatible types in array literal expression". How should I annotate "x" in order to clear this error?

For those who are interested, I need to create the array to pass values to SQLite.

Additionally, what would be the syntax for the same when using this as a parameter to a function call, such as an SQLite insert...

```
db.transaction.executeSql("...", [ep.id, ep.TY], ...);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `any[]` for your array's type.

Comment: Can you elaborate; I thought it was something like that but cannot seem to find the syntax. any[ep.id, ep.TY] is apparently incorrect according to the playground.

Comment: `var x:any[] = [ep.id, ep.TY];`

Comment: [Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20EP%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20TY%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20constructor(id%3A%20number%2C%20ty%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.id%20%3D%20id%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.TY%20%3D%20ty%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20ep%20%3D%20new%20EP(1%2C%20%22Yes%22)%3B%0Avar%20x%20%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5Bep.id%2C%20ep.TY%5D%3B%0A)

Comment: @Jacob: Fantastic. Any idea how I might do it if creating the array on the fly to pass as a function parameter (I only recently added this to my OP).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Also fantastic - I too am using the playground. Again, any idea how I might do it if creating the array on the fly to pass as a function parameter (I only recently added this to my OP).

Comment: You would be using dynamic typing if you needed to do that. There is no runtime type support; this is all just for the sake of the compiler. If you need the types to vary across calls, you'd have to use an `any[]` each time or `any` if it could also not be an array.

Comment: @MartinRobins You mean like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20EP%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20TY%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20constructor(id%3A%20number%2C%20ty%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.id%20%3D%20id%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.TY%20%3D%20ty%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20ep%20%3D%20new%20EP(1%2C%20%22Yes%22)%3B%0Avar%20x%20%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5Bep.id%2C%20ep.TY%5D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20transmogrifyArray(myArray%20%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0A%09myArray%5B0%5D%20%3D%20%22bop%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AtransmogrifyArray(%5Bep.id%2C%20ep.TY%5D)%3B%0A%0A)?

Comment: `db.transaction.executeSql("...", <any[]>[ep.id, ep.TY], ...);`

Comment: I'd also note that have to add this annotation shouldn't be required going forward (and arguably never should have been).  The compiler should infer a "best common type" for expressions where multiple types need to be taken into account (e.g. functions with multiple return statements, or array literals).  See section 3.10 in the latest spec updates (http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/bb540c9d3a78#file_diff_doc/TypeScript Language Specification.docx )